# Getting an image to turn into a gif on hover, and revert to static after

Tags: javascript, html, css, gif

I'm trying to get this ad to work, and I have it set up so that it will turn into a gif onMouseOver, and thats working fine, but I want it to go back to the static image onMouseOut. Here is my code

**HMTL**

```html
<div class="RightAdvert">
  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easy_Cheese" target="_blank">
    <img id="animation" class="advertisment" src="squeezy-cheesy.png" width="160" height="600" alt="Squeezy Cheesy advertisment" onMouseOver="playAnimation()" onmouseout="">
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.RightAdvert {
  float: left;
  width: 8%;
}
```

*The Advertisment class doesn't have any styles*

**Script**

```js
<script>
  function playAnimation() {
    document.getElementById('animation').src = "squeezy-cheesy2.gif";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: create a stopAnimation() function same with your playAnimation but this time your src is the original image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method on `onmouseout` event, `onmouseout="showStatic()`

```
<div class="RightAdvert">
                <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easy_Cheese" target="_blank">
                    <img id="animation" class="advertisment" src="squeezy-cheesy.png" width="160" height="600" alt="Squeezy Cheesy advertisment" onMouseOver="playAnimation()" onmouseout="showStatic()">
                </a>

</div>
```

Then change the `gif` with static image in `function showStatic()` function:

```
<script>
function playAnimation()
{
    document.getElementById('animation').src = "squeezy-cheesy2.gif";

}
function showStatic()
{
    document.getElementById('animation').src = "squeezy-cheesy.png";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, and is there a way to get the gif to play once and then go back to static?